# Conda environments don't do anything

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

I've installed conda on multiple machines, but no matter what permissions I change or even on a fresh install on linux, I will always get the issue "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable" when installing anything, including through pip and a normal requirments.txt. Am I missing something? Everything else works, can be installed, etc but when changing envirmments, even after a reboot it will always default to that making it pointless since it just treats it like it isn't there in the first place.

For example, if I have env1 and env2, activating env1, check that it's actually activated, and then run pip install -r requirements.txt it will install everything as expected but with that error. The software will run and be perfectly fine. But then if I reboot, or use deactivate, or anything else to switch envirmments and activate env2, then go install another version of torch or example, it'll give the same error, then uninstall the other version and install the new one.

Changed permission of the directories, reinstalled on multiple machines, run from inside the environment, leaving the base also and then loading the environment.

It's installed in the default location:  kl/home/anaconda3/

Looking to fix it so that when I activate an environment it actually installs into the environment.

Comment: How exactly do you change into your conda env? Where did you install conda? root?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you aware that new environments do not include `python` or `pip`? It sounds like you are creating empty environments and repeatedly running the system `pip`.

Comment: @merv I agree that it sounds like the system's pip is called, but it should fall back to the `pip` in base in case of an empty env, shouldn't it? But there might still be an alias set like `pip->/usr/bin/pip3` which I have seen frequently as the cause for such problems

Comment: @FlyingTeller the default activation strategy only leaves `condabin/` on PATH, and that should only expose `conda`, `mamba`, etc. globally. The Python and Pip from base should not be available when base is not active. There was a time before v4.4 that this was not the case, but that is maybe 5 years ago. There is also plenty of misguiding that tells uses to manually add the base `bin/` to PATH, but that is substandard.